# Is Applescript processing new folders that are created in the moment the script runs?

Tags: list, duplicates, applescript

I am working on a script that duplicates folders from an afp share to a local folder and does all kind of things with those folders afterwards. (it deletes the original folders after duplicating)

This code is working fine:

```
tell application "Finder"
duplicate every folder of folder afpFolder to localFolder with replacing
delete every folder of folder afpFolder
end tell
```

**My problem is** that our employees will be adding new folders to `afpFolder` regulary and quite often. My script is running every 10 seconds (with LaunchAgents) because it needs to process the duplicated data as often as possible.

**The question I have is: What happens when the script is duplicating and deleting folders and in the *exact* same moment somebody adds a new folder to `afpFolder`?**

Does the script only delete what was in `afpFolder` in the moment it started running ***or could it be that it would delete one of those newly created folders without duplicating it?***

I have also thought about making something with a list. For example:

```
set folderList to {}
tell application "Finder" to set folderList to every folder of afpFolder
duplicate folderList to localFolder
delete folderList
```

(this might not work this way)

Can anyone please help me answer the question?

**Can I work with the upper code where I just duplicate and delete? Or do I have to worry** about the script deleting folders that are created in the moment the script runs, without duplicating them?

If the upper code can cause trouble, can you help me with the list solution?

Comment: Why are you duplicating and deleting rather than just moving?

Comment: I know there is move, we just had some issues with it and started using duplicate + delete. (issues with folders not getting deleted, probably due to hd error or a permission problem)

Answer (score 1):

The first script would delete items that are added between the duplicate and delete commands. But I can't think of any case where the second approach would not work:

```
tell application "Finder"
    set l to items of ((POSIX file "/private/tmp/test") as alias)
    duplicate l to desktop
    delete l
end tell
```

You could also try using mv or rsync:

```
do shell script "mv /path/to/afp_folder/* /path/to/local_folder/"
do shell script "rsync -a /path/to/afp_folder/ /path/to/local_folder/
rm -r /path/to/afp_folder/*"
```

Comment: Hi Lauri. You should point out how to quote paths with spaces in them in your second example. +1

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I can't upvote it due to lack of reputation.

See my answer to see how I solved the problem.

Answer (score 0):

The code from your answer @John Alarik  is inefficient and I think in some spots it won't even work. Please don't take that as a criticism because I can see you're trying hard to find a solution which is the right way to go about getting help. So I thought I'd help with your code.

First you seem to be doing many unnecessary conversions of strings, alias's, and file specifications. In addition some of them are incorrect in the context you are using them and will probably cause errors. Your repeat statement in overly complicated too.

Try this code. It works in the same manner as you want but is much cleaner and shouldn't have any errors. I hope it helps. Good luck.

```
set afpFolder to "examplepath:path:folder:" as alias
set localFolder to "examplepath:path:folder:" as alias

tell application "Finder"
    set folderList to folders of afpFolder
    repeat with aFolder in folderList
        duplicate aFolder to localFolder with replacing
        delete aFolder
    end repeat
end tell
```

Comment: Hi regulus, thank you very much! I will change that tomorrow. I didn't take it as criticism because I almost knew, there would be easier and cleaner solutions... That's a bit what confuses me about AS... you always seem to have many ways of accomplishing something. For a newbie this is quite strange... But anyway, I did not learn AS from scratch, which I should if I really want to use it. This is just a side project where I had to find a solution for a change in a script that my buddy made. I will accept your answer when I have tried it. At least today, my code did work too... :-)

Comment: by the way: I found "my" solution here: http://forums.macrumors.com/showthread.php?t=274631

Comment: One guy there wrote something about the conversion to strings... I see that your code does not even have any "i to 1"-things in it. They are very hard to understand for me so I can't really follow what "my" code does. Your code really is as straightforward / human-readable as AS normally seems to be. But I guess, there is also cases where you need this "i to 1"-stuff?

Comment: Applescript works with paths, not strings. That's why we add "as alias" to the end of the strings in the first 2 lines. We're converting the string to a format applescript understands. We would only convert the path back into a string if we wanted to modify it but then once modified we would have to convert that string back into a path for applescript. You don't need to modify any of your paths thus there's no reason to ever use strings again. Even when you ask the Finder for a list of folders, the Finder gives you paths directly (not strings) so again you don't need to use any strings.

Answer (score 0):

Don't make it more complicated than it needs to be.

Both Duplicate and Delete can accept a list as a direct parameter. There is no need for any repeat loops. Please note that this is the same format that Lauri suggested, just formatted with the OP's example. Give her the upvote.

```
set afpFolder to "examplepath:path:folder:" as alias
set localFolder to "examplepath:path:folder:" as alias

tell application "Finder"
    set folderList to folders of afpFolder
    duplicate folderList to localFolder
    delete folderList
end tell
```

Answer (score -1):

Update: See @regulus6633's post about this code!

Thanks for all the help. In the meantime I could solve my problem even without your answers due to a good code snippet I found for making and processing a list.

This is the final solution, which works fine even if you copy a new folder to afpFolder while the script is running.

```
tell application "Finder"
  set afpFolder to "examplepath:path:folder:" as alias
  set localFolder to "examplepath:path:folder:" as string
  set folderList to every folder of folder afpFolder
    set i to 1
    repeat the count of folderList times
    set afpUniqueFolder to (item i of folderList) as string
        duplicate afpUniqueFolder to localFolder
        delete afpUniqueFolder
    set i to i + 1
    end repeat
end tell
```

I know that there is also a command called `move` instead of `duplicate` and `delete`.

We had some strange issues with `move` before, so since then I stick to `duplicate` and `delete`.

Thanks to all! This website is very helpful!